# Error in smoothing NDVI (BISE) using SPIRITS

Tags: ndvi, time-series, timesat

I want to minimize the spikes caused by cloud cover (smooth) NDVI timeseries data before applying Savitzky–Golay filter in Timesat. My previous post was also related to timeseries ([Interpreting NDVI curve in Timesat?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296385/interpreting-ndvi-curve-in-timesat)). I have gone through a paper "*Extraction of Agricultural Phenological Parameters of Sri Lanka Using MODIS, NDVI Time Series Data*(DOI: **10.1016/j.profoo.2016.02.027**) The author used **periodicity converter** tool in SPIRITS to minimize the spikes. I am also using similar tool *"processing-> temporal-> smoothing"* and also used periodicity converter tool but I ended up with error(below)

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

2018/11/13 05:34:01 STATE:   RUNNING
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    Task SMOOTH15_ISA.exe
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(0) : 'GUI'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(1) : '10'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(2) : '1'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(3) : '36'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(4) : '20150101'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(5) : '20171231'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(6) : 'G:\Spirits\3yrs\Image_File\vt'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(7) : '6'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(8) : 'i'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(9) : '0'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(10) : '0'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(11) : ' '
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(12) : ' '
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(13) : ' '
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(14) : '0'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(15) : '0'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(16) : '10'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(17) : '1'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(18) : '36'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(19) : '20150101'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(20) : '20171231'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(21) : 'G:\output\smooth\sw_vt'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(22) : '1'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(23) : 'i'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(24) : ' '
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(25) : ' '
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(26) : ' 0.0'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(27) : '75'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(28) : '0'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(29) : '1'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(30) : '2'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:    parameter(31) : 'G:\Downloads\SpiritsExtract_152(1)\libs\GLIMPSE\GLIMPSE_TMP\sm14sm_6561240588128570923'
2018/11/13 05:34:01 INFO:

---

SMOOTH15: SMOOTH SERIES of any VI (NDVI, fAPAR,...) & MODIFY the PERIODICITY

---

```
IN-SERIES: Periodicity
```

p1.Periodicity in Days [1-30]. NB: 10=def=civil dekads, 30=civil months
 p2.Account for Leap Years [0/1=def]. If 0, the series skips 29 February.
 p3.Periods per Year. Skip if period=1/5/10 or 30 (if p1=5 => 73 periods/year) 
    IN-SERIES: Start/End of entire series of IN-IMGs (incl. PREV/HIST, p10-13) 
 p4.IN-date1 [YYYYMMDD]    NB: - IN-Dates (p4/5) are reset to start of period
 p5.IN-date2 [YYYYMMDD]        - Period p4-p5 must at least cover 180 days
    IN-SERIES: NAMES OF ACTUAL IMGs: PiDiSi.img (BYTE, fixed MAPINFO/VALUES!)
 p6.Pi=Prefix             (add drive/path if needed)
 p7.Di=Date-Format [1-6]  (6 different formats, see below)
 p8.Si=Suffix             (no extension)
    1.YYYYMMDD  4.YYmDD     Year : YYYY[1950-2049] or  YY[50-49]
    2.YYMMDD    5.YYYYPP    Month: MM[01-12]       or   m[A=Jan...L=Dec]
    3.YYYYmDD   6.YYPP      Day:   DD[01-31]  Period_in_year: PP[(0)01-(n)nn]
    IN-SERIES: OTHER PARAMETERS concerning the TIME SERIES
 p9.Max. Nr. consecutively missing ACT IMGs                     [def=0, max=90]
p10.IMGs of Pre/Hist Year replace missing IMGs at edges [def=0=No,1=Pre,2=Hist]
    IN-SERIES: NAMES OF these IMGs of PREV/HIST YEAR: PhDhSh.img
p11.Ph=Prefix             (add drive/path if needed - If p10=0 => Skip p11-p13)
p12.Dh=Date-Format [1-6]  (6 formats, see above - HIST IMGs have YYYY=1962!)
p13.Sh=Suffix             (no extension)
    IN-SERIES: PROFILE TAILS: Improve extrapolation at start/end of IN-series
    NB: Only allowed if IN-series covers exactly one/more full years, else Skip
p14.Periods to copy from Profile-End   before Profile-Start        [def=0=none]
p15.                from Profile-Start after  Profile-End          [def=0=none]
    OUT-SERIES: Periodicity
p16.Periodicity in Days [1-30]. NB: 10=def=civil dekads, 30=civil months
p17.Account for Leap Years [0/1=def]. If 0, the series skips 29 February.
p18.Periods per Year. Skip if period=1/5/10 or 30 (if p18=5 => 73 periods/year)
    OUT-SERIES: Start/End dates
p19.OUT-Date1 [YYYYMMDD]  NB: - OUT-Dates (p19/20) are reset to start of period
p20.OUT-Date2 [YYYYMMDD]      - Defaults: adapted from IN-Dates (p4-p5)
    OUT-SERIES: NAMES OF OUT-IMGs: PoDoSo.img
p21.Po=Prefix            (add drive/path if needed)
p22.Do=Date-Format [1-6] (6 diff. formats - see above)
p23.So=Suffix            (no extension)
    OTHER PARAMETERS concerning the TIME SERIES OF IN/OUT-IMGs
p24.Name (no ext.) of VAR/MTA-files with names of OUT-IMGs (blank=none)
p25.Lowest physical value Ymin for cloudfree land pixels    [def=Vint+Vslo*Vlo]
p26.Eliminate local Minima if Y-difference to neighbours > YmaxDip [def=0=skip]
p27.Max. % of missing values in each pixel-profile               [0-99, def=75]
p28.Extrapolate 'TAILS' with missing IN-values                        [def=0/1]
    0=>Normal pixels may have flagged TAILS at start/end of profile
    1=>All normal pixels will only contain 'good' (non-flagged) OUT-values
p29.Method for OUT-Flags (most often only in profile TAILS)         [def=0/1/2]
    Always possible:        0 = Only 2 flags (254=water, 251=missing over land)
    IN/OUT-IMGs UNIflagged: 1 = Minimize OUT-flagged observations
    (251-255)               2 = Recover IN-flags 251=Missing and 253=Snow
p30.Smoothing: 0=MEAN, 1=BISE (only S10-inputs), 2=def=SWETS, 3=WHITTAKER
p31.SPP-file with fixed Specifications (ASCII, no ext. *.SPP)
    OPTIONAL OUT-IMGs with QUALITY INFORMATION and NAMES PqDqSq.img
p32.Pq=Prefix            (add drive/path if needed - blank = none)
p33.Dq=Date-Format [1-6] (6 diff. formats - see above)
p34.Sq=Suffix            (no extension)
p35.Max. allowed difference Ydelt: Smoothed <> PRE-treated IN-values  [def=0.0]

---

```
IN-SERIES: Periodicity
```

p1.Periodicity in Days     [1-30, def=10] =>10
 p2.Account for Leap Years       [0/1=def] =>1
 p3.Periods per Year               [fixed] =>36
    IN-PERIOD: Start/End of complete series of IN-IMGs (incl. PREV/HIST)
 p4.Date in FIRST IN-Period    [YYYYMMDD] =>20150101
 p5.Date in LAST  IN-period    [YYYYMMDD] =>20171231
    Nr. of IN-Periods   : 108 (or circa 1080 days)
    NAMES OF ACTUAL/REAL IN-IMGs: PiDiSi.img
 p6.Prefix Pi  (add drive/path if needed) =>G:\Spirits\3yrs\Image_File\vt
    1.YYYYMMDD  4.YYmDD     Year : YYYY[1950-2049] or  YY[50-49]
    2.YYMMDD    5.YYYYPP    Month: MM[01-12]       or   m[A=Jan...L=Dec]
    3.YYYYmDD   6.YYPP      Day:   DD[01-31]  Period_in_year: PP[01-36]
 p7.Date-Format Di (see above)      [1-6] =>6
 p8.Suffix Si       (no extension: *.IMG) =>i
    OTHER PARAMETERS concerning the TIME SERIES OF IN-IMGs
 p9.Max. Nr. of consec. missing ACT. IMGs in centre of series =>0
p10.Extend Series at edges: 0=No, 1=Prev.IMGs, 2=Hist.IMGs    =>0
    Nr. of ACTUAL IN-IMGs found: 0 (  0.00% of total periods 108)
2018/11/13 05:34:01 **ERROR**:   SMOOTH15-INPUT STAGE: Insuffient number of ACTUAL IN-IMGs (0) found
2018/11/13 05:34:01 STATE:   ERROR
2018/11/13 05:34:01 **ERROR**:   Program ended with exit code: 1*

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**NOTE:** I have input 3 years NDVI MOD13Q1 images (.img, .hdr format)

ENVI
description = {
G:\Spirits\3yrs\Image_File\2015_1.img}
samples = 8709
lines   = 4636
bands   = 1
header offset = 0
file type = ENVI Standard
data type = 2
interleave = bsq
byte order = 0
map info = {Geographic Lat/Lon, 1, 1, 85.13811073, 29.99895833, 0.00215682537558847, 0.00215682537553926,WGS-84}
coordinate system string = {GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]}
band names = {
Band 1}

I am unable to figure out the error caused. Anyone??